# HTML DIV alignment with label

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following DIV:

```
    <div id="IDVal">

    </div>
```

What I am doing is through Jquery passing a value for the id. I like to give a label to this div
to where the label and div tag's text align properly horizontally. I am having a problem aligning a label with the DIV.

Comment: show us the markup/css you've already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `label` and `div` have the correct `text-align` css property set. Also make sure that the `div` is not adding `padding` or the `label` is not adding a `margin`. A good start would be to include [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) in your site. Either copy the contents to the top of your existing CSS file or add this as a new CSS file to your project and include it before your main CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Divs by default have the display:block; css property, so that might be your problem, it breaks a like after it.

If you want it to be aligned horizontally, you should:

1. Float them both
2. Or give the css display:inline-block; to the div.